Let $p$ and $q$ be positive real numbers with $1/p+1/q=1$ prove that: $\frac13\le \frac1{p(p+1)}+\frac1{q(q+1)}\le\frac 12$.
Let $p$ and $q$ be positive real numbers with $1/p+1/q=1$ prove that
$$\frac13\le \frac1{p(p+1)}+\frac1{q(q+1)}\le\frac 12$$
From
$$q=\frac{p}{p-1}>0$$
I have that  $p,q>1$. Using differential calculus on the function
$$g(p)=\frac{1}{p(p+1)}+\frac{(p-1)^2}{p(2p-1)}$$
obtained by making substitution $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ gives
$$g'(p)=3p\frac{p-2}{2p^2+p-1}$$
Then I have a minimum point at $p=2$, $g(2)=\frac13$, and $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}g(p)=\frac12$.
Is there a simpler argument to obtain the inequality above?

Maybe, when you subtract $1/3$, there is a factor $p-2$, and when you subtract $1/2$, there is a factor $p-1$

$\infty$ is not a real number; why was $p=1,q=\infty$ needed?

I don't know if this helps but $p =\frac q{q-1}$ and $q=\frac p{p-1}$.  And you know more than $p,q \ge 1$.  You know $p,q > 1$.

Observe that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{p}(p+1)+\frac1q(q+1)=1+\frac1p+1+\frac1q=3.
\end{align}
An application of  Jensen's inequality with $\phi(x)=\frac1x$ yields
$$\frac13=\phi\Big(\frac{1}{p}(p+1)+\frac1q(q+1)\Big)\leq\frac1{p(p+1)}+\frac1{q(q+1)}\leq\max\Big(\frac{1}{p+1},\frac{1}{q+1}\Big)\leq\frac12$$
The last inequality follows from the fact that $1\leq p,q$ and $\phi$ is monotone decreasing.

$$P:=pq=p+q>0$$
Moreover, since the roots $p,q$ of
$$X^2-PX+P$$
are real numbers, its discriminant is $\ge0$ hence
$$P\ge4.$$
Now,
$$\begin{align}T(P)&:=\frac1{p(p+1)}+\frac1{q(q+1)}\\
&=\frac{p^2+q^2+p+q}
{pq(pq+p+q+1)}\\
&=\frac{(P^2-2P)+P}
{P(P+P+1)}\\&=\frac{P-1}{2P+1}.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$\frac12>T(P)\ge T(4)=\frac13.$$
Remark. More generally, let $x_i$ ($i=1,2$) be two real numbers with product $P>0$ and sum $S=kP$ (hence $k\ne0$). We then have $0\le S^2-4P=P(k^2P-4)$, i.e.
$$P\ge\frac 4{k^2}.$$
Now,
$$\begin{align}T_k(P)&:=\frac1{x_1(x_1+1)}+\frac1{x_2(x_2+1)}\\
&=\frac{S^2-2P+S}
{P(P+S+1)}\\
&=\frac{k^2P+k-2}{(k+1)P+1}.
\end{align}
$$
If $k>-1$,
$$\frac{k^2}{k+1}>T_k(P)\ge T_k\left(\frac 4{k^2}\right)=\frac{k^2(k+2)}{4(k+1)+k^2}.$$
For $k=1$, we recover the previous inequalities.

My first observation is that
$$\begin{align} \frac {1}{p \left( p + 1 \right)} & = \frac {1}{p} - \frac {1}{p + 1},\\ \frac {1}{q \left( q + 1 \right)} & = \frac {1}{q} - \frac {1}{q + 1},\end{align}$$
so
$$\frac {1}{p \left( p + 1 \right)} + \frac {1}{q \left( q + 1 \right)} = 1 - \frac {1}{p + 1} - \frac {1}{q + 1},$$
where
$$\begin{align} \frac {1}{p + 1} + \frac {1}{q + 1} & = \frac {p + q + 2}{\left( p + 1 \right) \left( q + 1 \right)} \\ & = \frac {1 / p + 1 / q + 2 / (p q)}{\left( 1 + 1 / p \right) \left( 1 + 1 / q \right)} \\ & = \frac {1 / p + 1 / q + 2 / (p q)}{1 + 1 / p + 1 / q + 1 / (p q)} \\ & = \frac {1 + 2 / (p q)}{2 + 1 / (p q)} = \frac {p q + 2}{2 p q + 1} = \frac {1}{2} + \frac {3 / 2}{2 p q + 1}. \end{align}$$
Accordingly,
$$\frac {1}{p \left( p + 1 \right)} + \frac {1}{q \left( q + 1 \right)} = \frac {1}{2} - \frac {3 / 2}{2 p q + 1}.$$
Obviously, then,
$$\boxed {\frac {1}{p \left( p + 1 \right)} + \frac {1}{q \left( q + 1 \right)} < \frac {1}{2}.}$$
By the AM-GM inequality,
$$1 = \frac {1}{p} + \frac {1}{q} \ge 2 \sqrt {\frac {1}{p} \cdot \frac {1}{q}} = \frac {2}{\sqrt {p q}},$$
so
$$\begin{align} \sqrt {p q} \ge 2, \quad & \Longrightarrow \quad p q \ge 4, \\ & \Longrightarrow \quad 2 p q + 1 \ge 9, \\ & \Longrightarrow \quad \frac {3 / 2}{2 p q + 1} \le \frac {1}{6}, \end{align}$$
whence we derive
$$\boxed {\frac {1}{p \left( p + 1 \right)} + \frac {1}{q \left( q + 1 \right)} \ge \frac {1}{3}.}$$
We have completed the proof. $\blacksquare$

Thank you very much, terrific , i appreciate it.

For the right inequality
Clearly, $p, q > 1$. We have
$$\frac1{p(p+1)} + \frac1{q(q+1)}
< \frac1{p(1+1)} + \frac1{q(1+1)} = \frac12.$$

Denoting $\frac{1}{p}=\cos^2 t, \ \frac{1}{q}=\sin^2 t$ and since $\cos^2 t\sin^2 t\in \left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right] $ we get
$$\frac{1}{p(p+1)}+\frac{1}{q(q+1)}=\frac{1-\cos^2 t\sin^2 t}{2+\cos^2 t\sin^2 t}\in \left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

Hi! You seem to find this equality obvious. Do you have a shorter method than ours to prove it?

Note ${\sin}^{2} \left( t \right) , {\cos}^{2} \left( t \right) = \frac {1}{4} , {\sin}^{2} \left( 2 t \right)$. Now $\left( 1 - 0 \right) / \left( 2 + 0 \right) = \frac {1}{2}$ and $\left( 1 - \frac {1}{4} \right) / \left( 2 + \frac {1}{4} \right) = \frac {1}{3}$. (I am writing this for the record.)

This was obvious. What is not is the equality (and the usefulness of the trigonometric functions).

Anne: Just use $\frac{1}{\cos^2 t}=1+\tan^2 t$ and    $\frac{1}{\sin^2 t}=1+\cot^2 t.$

Thank you Gérard but I don't see how it helps.
